# storing forum posts in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, forum, phpbb3

phpBB stores forum [post texts](http://wiki.phpbb.com/Tables/phpbb_posts) in a strange way (like: [BLOB - 115 B]), what is it? How it is done?

Comment: Instead of the actual text it shows me something like [BLOB - 115 B] or [BLOB - 266 B]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BLOB (Binary Large Object) is a large collection of binary data stored in a database table. Different database servers handles BLOB differently. But there are some common characteristics like:

- BLOB stores binary data, which
  requires no encoding schema. BLOB
  data is stored in units of bytes.
- BLOB data is usually large. Many
  database servers offer very high
  maximum sizes like 4 GB.
- BLOB data is    usually not directly
  stored inside       the table. It is
  stored in different     storage areas
  and its reference       address is
  stored inside the table.